# How to determine if there is a line break in selected text

Tags: javascript, selection

**Context**

I have a website where users can write articles. Users can hit "enter" to create a new `div`, which brings them to a new line. Once the article is published, other users can select any text on the article and respond to it. However, I don't want users to be able to highlight text on multiple lines. So, for example, if an article has the following content:

```
First line here.
Second line here.
```

The users should be allowed to highlight anything on the first or second line alone (`First line` could be highlighted, for example), but I don't want them to be able to make a highlight that includes both lines, like so:

```
here.
Second line
```

**Question**

How can I check for a line break like this in jQuery? Is there a character I can check for using regular expressions or something of that sort?

I use the following code to get the selection in the first place:

```
if (window.getSelection) {

    sel = window.getSelection();

} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {

    sel = document.selection.createRange();

}

//do something with selected text
```

Can I add something after I get the selection to check for this? Maybe something like this (this example doesn't work):

```
var match = /\r|n\/.exec(sel);

if (match) {

//do something

}
```

Let me know if there is any confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code will work except for an issue in the regex expression that you have shared.

Instead of

```
var match = /\r|n\/.exec(sel);
```

It should be

```
var match = /\r|\n/.exec(sel);
```

But it matches only one occurrence. To match all the occurrences, you need to loop the matching.
I have updated the code below.

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
  findHighlightedTexts();
});

function findHighlightedTexts(){
  var highlightedTexts = window.getSelection();
  var occurrence = 0;
  var regexp = /\r|\n/g;
  while(match=regexp.exec(highlightedTexts)) {
     // match is an object which contains info such as the index at which the matched keyword is present
     console.log(match);
      //Output the matched keyword which is new line character here.
     console.log("Keyword: ", match[0]);
      //Index at which the matched keyword is present.
     console.log("Index: ", match.index);
     occurrence++;
  }
  console.log("Total Occurrence: ", occurrence);
}
```

```html
<h3>Select the texts:</h3>
<div>
  This is Sentence1<br>
  This is Sentence2<br>
  This is Sentence3<br>
  This is Sentence4<br>
  This is Sentence5<br>
  This is Sentence6<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just want to get the first part of a string (the selection, in this case) up to the first line break.

In this example, `foo\nbar\rhello\nworld` is the selection.

```js
const [result] = 'foo\nbar\rhello\nworld'.split(/\n|\r/);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I beleive that’s not what OP wanted as per the question. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @GirkovArpa The answer you proposed is right. But it would be better if you could just assign the split results as an array instead of destructuring and include >1 check to know whether there are any line breaks. Just to check for line breaks as mentioned in the post, this should be fine. But in case the index is needed, it wouldn't be possible (Possible but Not directly) using this method as we can using match/exec functions.

Comment: To get an array of all the matches, `selection.match(/.+$/gm)`.  Or `selection.split(/\n|\r/g)`.  The `.length > 1` check works with these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `Regex` (regular expressions) to achieve what you want. To count line break in a `selected` text only.

I have recreated your example below where you type text in `textarea` with adding line breaks.

Once you are done adding `words` and `line breaks` you can `select` that text and click the `Count Line Break` button to see how many times you have added a new line (Line break)

> You can amend the `userSelection area` of text according to your needs by using `if` `else`

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
var userSelection
function countLineBreaks(){

  //Textarea
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textArea");  

  //Get user selection
  userSelection = (textarea.value).substring(textarea.selectionStart,textarea.selectionEnd);
  
  //Simple regex to check for line break
  var matches = userSelection.match(/\n/g);

  //Count line breaks
  var lineBreaksCount = matches ? matches.length : 0
   
  console.log(lineBreaksCount + ' Line breaks')
}
```

```html
<textarea col="50" rows="10" id="textArea" placeholder="Type here with line breaks"></textarea>
 <br>
<button onclick="countLineBreaks()">Count Line Break In Selected Text</button>
```